# Tailwind Object-fit doesn't function

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-variants

When trying to use object-contain in tailwind I get
`` Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `object-fit` supplied to `Image`. ``

This is my code `` <Image style={[tw`flex object-contain bg-red-400`, {width: '100%', height: '50%'}]} source={{uri: card.image}}/> `` BTW tried without width and height still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use resizeMode: 'contain'